# Multiple file renaming based on regex pattern + renaming within files based on new file names

Tags: file, rename, batch-processing, file-rename, batch-rename

How to achieve this? I have a folder with over 1000 code files, mostly xml.
Most of the files have a common pattern:
abbb
accc
addd

a should be placed by z:
zbbb
zccc
zddd

However, there are also files that do not start with a:
efff
ghhh

These names should then simply be preceded by z.
zefff
zghhh

Within the files various of the file names can show up. Hence, all original file names should be replaced by the new names within the files, too.
My idea was something like putting original names in column 1 of a table and put the new names in column 2 next to them. Then looping over this table and if an original name is found within a  file - it can also show up multiple times in code lines - and replace it with the new name. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it for me:

- File renaming e.g. as described here: https://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files
- Batch replacement with this VS Code plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=angelomollame.batch-replacer
- since I had the said table (old vs. new name) prepared, a simple regex replacement of the table entries did the trick to meet the prerequisites for the plugin, i. e. the old names were replaced by *replace "old_file_name"* and the new names by *with "new_file_name"*; then, just copy & paste everything for this plugin as described there and all is replaced